# Nginx worker_rlimit_nofile

Tags: nginx

How does one set `worker_rlimit_nofile` to a higher number and what's the maximum it can be or is recommended to be?

I'm trying to follow the following advice:

> The second biggest limitation that most people run into is also
> related to your OS. Open up a shell, su to the user nginx runs as and
> then run the command `ulimit -a`. Those values are all limitations
> nginx cannot exceed. In many default systems the open files value is
> rather limited, on a system I just checked it was set to 1024. If
> nginx runs into a situation where it hits this limit it will log the
> error (24: Too many open files) and return an error to the client.
> Naturally nginx can handle a lot more than 1024 files and chances are
> your OS can as well. You can safely increase this value.
>
> To do this you can either set the limit with ulimit or you can use
> worker_rlimit_nofile to define your desired open file descriptor
> limit.

From: https://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/

Answer (score 28):

`worker_rlimit_nofile` = `worker_connections` * 2 file descriptors

Each worker connection open 2 file descriptors (1 for upstream, 1 for downstream)

Comment: Even though the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_rlimit_nofile) are not 100% clear about that, it seems like `worker_rlimit_nofile` is [applied to each worker](https://www.masv.io/boost-nginx-connection-limits/). Therefore it makes no sense to multiply with `worker_processes`. But you may have to multiply by 2, since a worker needs 2 File Descriptors per Connection - one for the client, one for the served File (or upstream, proxy...).

Comment: According to the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections) you don't need to multiply by 2 as worker_connections should already include both types of connections (downstream and upstream).

Answer (score 18):

While setting `worker_rlimit_nofile` parameter, you should consider both `worker_connections` and `worker_processes`. You may want to check your OS's file descriptor first using: `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn` which will give you the per user hard and soft file limits respectively. You can change the OS limit using systemctl as:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=$VAL
```

where $VAL is the number you would like to set. Then, you can verify using:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

If you are automating the configuration, it is easy to set worker_rlimit_nofile as:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile = worker_connections*2
```

The worker_processes is set to 1 by default, however, you can set it to a number less than or equal to the number of cores you have on your server:

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

***EDIT:***
The latest versions of nginx set ***worker_processes: auto*** by default, which sets to the number of processors available in the machine. Hence, it's important to know why you would really to change it.

Normally, setting it to highest value or to all available processors doesn't always improve the performance beyond certain limit: it's likely you get the same performance by setting it to 24 vs 32 processors. Some kernel/TCP-stack parameters could also help mitigate bottle-necks.

And in micro-services deployment (kubernetes), it's very important to consider pod resource request/limits while setting these configurations.

To check how many workers process nginx has spawned you could run **ps -lfC nginx**. e.g. on my machine I got the following, since my machine has 12 processors, nginx spawned 12 worker processes.

```
$ ps -lfC nginx
F S UID          PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
5 S root       70488       1  0  80   0 - 14332 -      Jan15 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
5 S www-data   70489   70488  0  80   0 - 14526 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:24 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70490   70488  0  80   0 - 14525 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:41 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70491   70488  0  80   0 - 14450 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:49 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70492   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:37 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70493   70488  0  80   0 - 14447 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:44 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70494   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:46 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70495   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:34 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70496   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:31 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70498   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:46 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70499   70488  0  80   0 - 14449 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:50 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70500   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:39 nginx: worker process
5 S www-data   70501   70488  0  80   0 - 14433 -      Jan15 ?        00:08:41 nginx: worker process
```

To print the exact count, you could you UID (e.g. for my setup it's UUID is www-data. which is configured in nginx.conf as user www-data;)

```
$ ps -lfC nginx | awk '/nginx:/ && /www-data/{count++} END{print count}'
12
```

In kubernetes, nginx spawn worker processes depending on the resource request for the pod by default.
e.g if you have the following in your deployment:

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: 2048Mi
    cpu: 2000m
```

Then nginx will spawn 2 worker process (2000 milli cpu = 2 cpu)

Comment: Not sure whether the formula is correct: `worker_rlimit_nofile = (worker_connections * worker_processes) * 2`. There seems to be widespread consensus that the correct formula is the one in Azad's answer. The formula in this answer yields the correct result by accident if nginx only has 1 worker process.

Comment: @Manuel agreed, indeed this works only if worker process is set 1, which used to be the default value. I updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: It might sound obvious for some, but I would clarify that `worker_connections` SHOULD be defined from `worker_rlimit_nofile` and not the other way round, as the latter is, theoretically, equal to the `open files` number given by typing `ulimit -a` in the terminal. e.g. if `open files` = 1024, then `worker_rlimit_nofile` = 1024 and worker_connections = 512;