# NGINX in containerized deployement retruns error "getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576"

Tags: nginx, containers

When we moved to Azure for testing our deployments, NGINX returns error which seems to be OS level error.

Same deployment works well on other cloud platforms, also the OS version is maintained uniform across all our testing cloud platforms.

OS version:

```
Linux version 4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29)
```

Docker container error:

```
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: using the "epoll" event method
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: nginx/1.21.6
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: OS: Linux 4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: start worker processes
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: start worker process 15
2022/03/04 14:42:58 [notice] 14#14: start worker process 16
```

PLease advise.

Comment: Seem to be a duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/q/37591784/1765658